# Align EditText to TextView using RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How can I align the TextView & EditText so both could be at the same size and the same line, using RelativeLayout?

both of their top margins can start at the same horizontal line, or end at the same horizontal line. But is looks like one above the another...

[image]

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_txtSensorPitch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_comment"
            android:text="@string/tv_txtSensorPitch"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_sensorPitch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_txtSensorPitch"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_txtSensorPitch"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Comment: Use `Linear Layout` to make it look like as you want with weight sum in horizontal orientation

Answer (score 0):

Use android:layout_width=0 and android:layout_weight=1

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them into a linearlayout and give weight:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_txtSensorPitch"    
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_sensorPitch"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="dfsdfs : "
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="fgfgfgfgfg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I have used weight attribute = 1 for linear layout and divided equals weights between `TextView` and `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` inside `RelativeLayout` with horizontal orientation having android:weight="1" on `TextView` and `EditText` add `android:layout_gravity="center"` to textview

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_txtSensorPitch"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_comment"
    android:text="Some Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_sensorPitch"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="Some TExt"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code

```
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_txtSensorPitch"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tv_comment"
     android:text="@string/tv_txtSensorPitch"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/et_sensorPitch"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_txtSensorPitch"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_txtSensorPitch"
     android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_txtSensorPitch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_comment"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_sensorPitch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Some TExt"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```